# How to display latex image in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I wish to write full latex code then show result as a image in org mode. My idea is:

1. Use EXAMPLE block to write full latex code.
2. Use emacs-lisp to compile the latex code to png.
3. Show png file but "file:latex.png".

Code as below:

```
#+NAME: latexcircle
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
\documentclass[convert={outfile=latex.png},border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
#+END_EXAMPLE

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var latexcode=latexcircle
(setq latexfile "tmp.tex")
(write-region latexcode nil latexfile)
(setq latexcmd (format "pdflatex --shell-escape %s" latexfile))
(shell-command-to-string latexcmd)
"file:latex.png"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: file:latex.png
```

The file latex.png is created successfully but the result doesn't show the image.
I try to use "file latex.png but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html) link

```
#+HEADER: :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :fit yes :file latex.png :imagemagick yes :iminoptions -density 600 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC
```

Output:
[image]